# find smallest number n in which have k relatively prime number in the interval [1,n]

Tags: algorithm, math, number-theory

Euler Totient Function finds the number of numbers from 1 to n that are relatively prime to n.

For example--

- phi(1) = 1
- phi(2) = 1
- phi(3) = 2
- phi(4) = 2
- phi(15) = 8
- phi(16) = 8
- phi(20) = 8
- phi(24) = 8
  . . . . . . . .
- phi(n) = x

Here 15, 16, 20, 24 have 8 numbers between 1 to them that are relatively prime. But 15 is the smallest number with number of co-primes = 8.

How to find 15 if we input 8

Find a general algorithm for finding the smallest n such that phi(n) = x for an arbitrary x where x <= 2*10^9

Comment: What are your constraints? Why cant you just loop from `1 to n+1th prime` (for input `n`) and check ETF value for each number?

Comment: What's the question? Is it specifically to compute the smallest n such that phi(n) = 8, or to find a general algorithm for finding the smallest n such that phi(n) = x for an arbitrary x?

Comment: Output must be gather than input. I can run loop from n+1 and when find a number which have n relatively prime number(using Euler totient function)  than stop. But If input number 2*10^9. Is it a efficient way????

Comment: For an arbitrary x, find the smallest number n where phi(n) = x

Comment: It's not easy, but here's a useful link: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265397/inversion-of-the-euler-totient-function

Comment: This is a very interesting question, but I believe it is off-topic. Perhaps you should ask it on https://math.stackexchange.com/ or https://mathoverflow.net/ ?
Toward an answer though, I would try and look at the factorizations of x, since there is a theorem that writes phi(n) as a product determined by the prime factorization of n.

Comment: I suspect that this question belongs to another stackexchange site..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a quite difficult math question, and there's already good answers on math.stackexchange (link already provided in comments).

Comment: Thanks all. This is my first question. "close this question" means should i need to delete this question?

Comment: Closing the question involves voting by the community to stop allowing answers and other interaction on the question. There are mechanisms that delete some but not all closed questions. Don't worry, this does not count "against" you. More details can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions